# Prevent default to send AJAX form data doesn't update front end?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I'm working in Flask and have prevented default with javascript in order to send all the data I need via an AJAX request. The problem now is that my view has all the data (I have confirmed with console outputs) but the front-end will not update with the passed through data. It was working before, but adding in this javascript function broke the application. It also doesn't allow the alert flashed messages to show like it used to on invalid form. Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // get old values
  var old_num_components = $("input[name='number_components']:checked").val();
  var old_method = $("#method_select").val();
  // get new values
  var new_num_components;
  var new_method;
  var data = {'new_num_components':'none','old_num_components':'none', 'new_method':'none','old_method':'none'};
  // var data = {};

  $("#submit_form_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    new_num_components= $("input[name='number_components']:checked").val();
    data.new_num_components = new_num_components;
    data.old_num_components = old_num_components;
    old_num_components=new_num_components;

    new_method= $("#method_select").val();
    //alert(old_method + " : " + new_method);
    data.new_method = new_method;
    data.old_method = old_method;
    old_method=new_method;

    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{{url_for('similar')}}",
      data:$("#main_form").serialize()+"&"+$.param(data)
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: I have tried reloading the window within the ajax call itself

`success: function(msg){window.location.reload(true);}`

Comment: This really needs to be reduced to an MVCE. Did you previously have no JavaScript and then you added 30 some-odd lines? Was some of this here when it was working previously? What's with all the commented-out LoC?

Comment: @JaredSmith I have other scripts but they are all dealing with the multiple tab display that I have. Before, I have a flask WTF form that submits and everything was updating perfectly fine. Then I introduced this script and the data sends but the front-end does not update any more. I can remove the script and it works as it should again.

Comment: You have to manually update the front end. This sounds like an XY problem. Just put the extra stuff you need in the form as hidden inputs and submit normally. Otherwise you'll have to update the DOM manually.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm sorry, could you elaborate? do I use the javascript function to feed the values I need into the hidden inputs and use it that way without the ajax call?

Comment: Yes. Do that then append the inputs to the form and call the form's `.submit()` method.

Comment: @JaredSmith if you would like to, please write out your comments as an answer instead of comments very briefly so that I may accept your help as the answer! Thanks a lot Jared

Comment: Done. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the extra info as hidden inputs and submit the form normally:

```
e.preventDefault();

var form = document.querySelector('#main-form');

Object.entries(data).forEach(function(key, value) {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = key;
  input.value = value;
  input.type = 'hidden';
  form.append(input);
});

form.submit();
```

Comment: I do have one question about this -- `Object.entries(data).(function(key, value)` isn't the syntax here incorrect with .(function() { ?

Comment: Ended up going with `      $.each(data,function(key,value){
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.name = key;
        input.value = value;
        input.type = 'hidden';
        form.append(input);
      });
      form.submit();`

Comment: @N.Kim should have been `Object.entries(data).forEach(function`, updated.